# Why is shapefile non recognised in the dataset?

Tags: shapefile, data, carto, geometry, web-mapping

Do CartoDB datasets accept .shp files for the geometry?

I should use them to build a map but I can't do it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 6):

CartoDB is looking for all extensions included in a shapefiles to be imported in a .zip package that contains, at least:

```
file.shp
file.shx
file.dbf
file.prj
```

Make sure you have included all those files in your .zip package

Here is a good tutorial - [Intro Guides Quick Data Import](https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/quick-data-import/)